# MySQL LEFT JOIN on list

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id | val1 | val2
----------------
1  |  100 |  200
2  |  200 |  100
3  |  150 |  250
```

And I get from an API a list like:

```
((1, 100, 200), 
 (2, 200, 101),
 (3, 150, 250))
```

From the list I get the same data from the table, there I can see that the column val2 from id 2 has changed from 100 to 101.

What kind of MySQL query will return the second row of the list?, that is, the row that had one of their values changed.

It should test for both val1 and val2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in()` operator with multiple fields with a list:

```
select * from table
where (id, val1, val2) not in ((1, 100, 200), 
                               (2, 200, 101),
                               (3, 150, 250))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The query returns id=2, val1=200, val2=100. Is there a way to return id=2, val1=200, val2=101?

Comment: Well, there is a way to do this in MySQL, but probably it would be easier if you did it in the application layer based on the ID. To make it work in sql you would have to insert the data from the API list into a temporary table, or assemble a derived table by breaking up the API list by rows and use a series of `union` to combine them together in sql.